# How to maintain the open/closed principle with inheritance hierarchies of objects in containers?

Tags: c++

When I want to add functionality to this structure, without changing it:

```
class MemberBase
{
public:
    virtual MemberBase* clone() const; 
    virtual void action1(); 
    ... 
}

class Container
{
public:
    virtual void functionUsingAction1();
    ...
private:
    std::vector<MemberBase*> members_
}
```

I can subclass MemberBase and

```
class MemberType1 : public MemberBase
{
public:
    MemberBase* clone() const;// Reimplementation
    void action1();           // Reimplementation
    virtual void action2();   // New functionality
}
```

I can fill the container with the desired type of data by employing the

```
MemberBase* MemberBase::clone() const;
```

Method. But how do I call

```
void MemberType1::action2();
```

from the methods of the Container class? I can use dynamic_cast, but that is considered a design flaw. Is there any workaround? Or better, any pattern I can follow?

Comment: First of all I would recommend reading about `boost::ptr_vector`. A `boost::ptr_vector<MemberBase>` would guarantee exception safety with not cost in your `Container`. Secondly, what are you really trying to achieve ? There are many ways to answer your question, it really depends on what's the problem at hand.

Comment: I believe, that in the Container class you wanted to write std::vector<MemberBase*> ?

Comment: Thank you! I am building a library of genetic algorithms. Each algorithm uses a container, but the requirements on the Container members change. For every algorithm there should be a specific MemberType class.

Comment: What class responce for calling new functionality "void MemberType1::action2()"?

Comment: @zabulus I want to call the  "void MemberType1::action2()" from methods of Container and types derived from Container

Comment: You are containing pointers to MemberBase, and want to call action2? There is no information about presence action2 method than using dynamic_cast. the easiest way is to add method action2 with empty implementation to the MemberBase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, the more I look at it and it looks like a typical [Visitor](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/visitor.html) application to me.

I would suggest avoiding implementing any intelligence in your `Container` class, and instead delegate the actions to a specific `Visitor` class. The base `Visitor` can be given some way to safely interact with the underlying container structure (erase/insert).

```
// MemberBase.hpp
class Visitor;

class MemberBase {
public:
  virtual MemberBase* clone() const = 0;

  virtual void accept(Visitor&) = 0;
  virtual void accept(Visitor&) const = 0;
}; // class MemberBase

// Visitor.hpp
class Member1;
class Member2;

class Visitor {
public:
  virtual void visit(Member1&) = 0;
  virtual void visit(Member1 const&) = 0;

  virtual void visit(Member2&) = 0;
  virtual void visit(Member2 const&) = 0;
};

// Container.hpp
#include <MemberBase.hpp>

class Container {
public:
  void accept(Visitor& v) {
    BOOST_FOREACH(MemberBase& mb, _members) {
      mb.accept(v);
    }
  }

  void accept(Visitor& v) const {
    BOOST_FOREACH(MemberBase const& mb, _members) {
      mb.accept(v);
    }
  }

private:
  boost::ptr_vector<MemberBase> _members;
};
```

Then you need to implement the member's `accept` methods. It's purely mechanical.

```
// Member1.hpp
#include <MemberBase.hpp>

class Member1: public MemberBase {
public:
  virtual Member1* clone() const { return new Member1(*this); }

  virtual void accept(Visitor& v);
  virtual void accept(Visitor& v) const;
};

// Member1.cpp
#include <Member1.hpp>
#include <Visitor.hpp>

void Member1::accept(Visitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
void Member1::accept(Visitor& v) const { v.visit(*this); }
```

And finally you can implement a visitor:

```
// CountVisitor.hpp
#include <Visitor.hpp>

class CountVisitor: public Visitor {
public:
  CountVisitor(): _count(0) {}

  size_t count() const { return _count; }

  virtual void visit(Member1&);
  virtual void visit(Member1 const&);

  virtual void visit(Member2&);
  virtual void visit(Member2 const&);

private:
  size_t _count;
};

// CountVisitor.cpp
#include <CountVisitor.hpp>
//#include <Member1.hpp> // where you would include, but unnecessary here

void CountVisitor::visit(Member1&) { ++_count; }
void CountVisitor::visit(Member1 const&) { ++_count; }

void CountVisitor::visit(Member2&) { ++_count; }
void CountVisitor::visit(Member2 const&) { ++_count; }
```

And you use it as:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <Container.hpp>
#include <CountVisitor.hpp>

int main() {
  Container const c = /* something */;

  CountVisitor cv;
  c.accept(cv);

  std::cout << cv.count() << " items in the container\n";
}
```

The weakness of this design is that a new `visit` method need be implemented for each new class directly deriving from `MemberBase`, and thus the `MemberBase` hierarchy is not so open. This can be alleviated using the [Acyclic Visitor](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/acv.pdf); however, I have rarely needed it.

To "extend" the ability, you can have `Visitor::visit` and `MemberBase::accept` return an "action" to be executed (erase, clone, etc...) and deal with this in the **two** loops you actually have. *It could be reduced to one loop using some tricks...*

Comment: OP said in comment that "requirements on the Container members change." I take that to mean they are unstable. So, doesn't this break the Visitor pattern? Visitors are the open part (the classes that can vary), and the Visitees (Containers in this case) are closed (supposed to be stable in the context of the pattern).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: I don't think so (and apparently neither does the OP since he accepted the answer). The requirements on `Container` changed before the introduction of the pattern, but now those changes are supported by the `Visitor` hierarchy which is open. I underlined the issue with introducing new types in the `MemberBase` rooted hierarchy at the end, which can be alleviated by the Acyclic Visitor pattern if necessary. I did not presented it here because it's more complicated and the answer was already long.

Comment: OK, I edited the next-to-last paragraph of your answer that said the Visitor hierarchy is not so open.

Answer (score 2):

If you know, that each member will publish different functions, you may always create methods like EnumerateActions(), CallAction(std::string action) and so on - which will be safer, but might be compared to shooting a sparrow with a bazooka.

Another option is to make interfaces: IAction1, IAction2 and implement them in the member derived classes. Then you just check, if a member implement an interface and use it. Container won't be aware of specific member classes, yet you will still be able to access their specific functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

One option I can think of o check each object whether it is MemberType1 object, and if the condition is true, then you can call the action2(). Its a very naive solution but I am sure someone else will soon come up with a smart one :)

Comment: He's already suggested that - I can use dynamic_cast, but that is considered a design flaw. Is there any workaround?